# Counter issues VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Struggling with this counter...

I am going through multiple pages of info and trying to count the number of overdue tasks then inserting this info into a statistics page.

```
Sub data_input_overdue()

Dim rw As Long
Dim Counter As Long

Dim col As Long
col = CountMyCols("Stats")

Worksheets("Stats").Cells(2, col + 1).Value = "Overdue"

Counter = 0


For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    For i = 2 To CountMyRows(sht.Name)
        c_date = Range("E" & i)
        dueDate = CDate(c_date)
        If dueDate < Date And sht.Range("I" & i).Value = "No" Then
        Counter = Counter + CLng(1)
        Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, col + 1).Value = Counter
    End If
    Next i
Next sht
End Sub

Public Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long
On Error Resume Next
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName)
    CountMyRows = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column
```

Its not counting and going into the right places in the table as well. I want it to go into a column starting on the 3rd row. 
In the multiple sheets there is a mixture of completed and uncompleted tasks

Comment: What we can see of the `CountMyRows` function seems to actually count columns. The result of the call to `.Cells.Find` has `.Column` applied to it which seems counter-intuitive

Comment: @barrowc sorry I wasn't clear. In the multiple sheets there are completed and uncompleted tasks so I can't just count the rows unfortunately.

Comment: @ZoeChu What barrowc is saying is that, in your `CountMyRows` function, you are returning the `.Column` of the last used cell in the last row.  You need to return the `.Row` instead.  (And, even with my coffee working its way through my bloodstream, I still haven't worked out what you are trying to write out - it may be best if you add some sample input and some sample expected output to your question.)

Comment: @YowE3K Yeah sorry just spotted that! Thanks

Comment: @barrowc Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Also, `c_date = Range("E" & i)` should be `c_date = sht.Range("E" & i)`

Comment: Are you just trying to get one single number - being the total number of overdue tasks on all worksheets?  Or are you trying to get a number for each worksheet (so 10 worksheets --> 10 numbers)?  Or are you trying to work out how many tasks are overdue in row 2 of all worksheets, and how many tasks are overdue in row 3 of all worksheets, etc (i.e. one number for each row)?

Comment: Overdue tasks on each sheet in a table. So the title of the row will be the sheet name. (yeah, 10 worksheets ----> 10 numbers) @YowE3K

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure how you will identify each total with the applicable sheet.

```
Sub data_input_overdue()
    Dim c_date
    Dim dueDate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim cntSheet As Long

    Dim col As Long
    col = CountMyCols("Stats")

    Worksheets("Stats").Cells(2, col + 1).Value = "Overdue"

    cntSheet = 0

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Stats" Then ' Don't process the Stats sheet
            cntSheet = cntSheet + 1
            'Reset counter at the start of each sheet
            Counter = 0
            For i = 2 To CountMyRows(sht.Name)
                c_date = sht.Range("E" & i)
                dueDate = CDate(c_date)
                If dueDate < Date And sht.Range("I" & i).Value = "No" Then
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                End If
            Next i
            'Update Stats sheet after finished counting
            Worksheets("Stats").Cells(2 + cntSheet, col + 1).Value = Counter
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub

Public Function CountMyRows(SName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName)
        CountMyRows = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
End Sub

Public Function CountMyCols(SName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName)
        CountMyCols = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Column
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If I was doing this, I would probably put the sheet names in column A and the totals in column B, or start with the sheet names in column A, and then use that sheet name to decide which sheet to process when calculating the total to put on that row (rather than just looping through all the sheets in tab order).